# req.file is undefined: uploading images in express using multer

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am trying to upload images in an express server using multer, however, uploading images using postman using the route below, gives the json message `{ msg: 'image uploaded successfully' }` (i.e., the route is reached correctly), but `req.file` gives `undefined`. Why? the related file structure is as follows, to make sure I am referencing the destination correctly:

-backend
--routes
---uploadRoutes.js
--server.js
-frontend
-uploads

uploadRoutes.js

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads');
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png/;
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (extname && mimetype) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb('Images only!');
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
  try {
    res.status(200).json({ msg: 'image uploaded successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
  // res.send(`/${req.file.path}`);
});

export default router;
```

Comment: How are you uploading the files from the frontend? Is it multipart/form-data?

Comment: I haven't reached the frontend yet. I am trying to upload images using postman right now. I simply write a POST request to the route `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/upload`, and in the body field I send an empty object `{}` in the raw option, and in the form-data I specify the key as `image` and the value is the image I want to upload, and it's one of the formats I check against.

Answer (score 0):

just check the `header` and `body form-data` request, because your code is correctly if you have this line in the app file

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
```

[image]

header of request

[image]

Comment: The header is there as you showed in the image. In the server.js file I use `app.use('/api/v1/uploads', uploadRoutes)`, where `uploadRoutes` are imported as `import uploadRoutes from './routes/uploadRoutes)`. What else could it be?